# Code Igniter issue with base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, uri, lighttpd

I moved a code-igniter page using two languages from xampp on windows to raspberry pi using lighttpd.

Now, my `base_url` doesn't seem to work properly.
The base_url should be "http://raspberry.local/test/" but when I enter that, all Links are broken.
When I change the `base_url` to "http://raspberry.local/test/index.php" the links work. They look like "http://raspberry.local/test/index.php/link/" but image-links are broken now.
Images are loaded like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url("/images/starte.png") ?>" alt="Start-Image" class="precomposed">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you changing `index.php` viewing in `.htaccess`?

Comment: I'm using lighttpd, so .htaccess is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we need to use this base_url()

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/starte.png" alt="Start-Image" class="precomposed">
```